# Unit test MockHttpServletRequest not returning content type

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, java-8, junit4

I would like the application to return JSON object from my Java Classes (both success and fail cases).

I had defined a `@RestControllerAdvice` to handle the errors from controller. My program also shows the error message correctly in json, but the problem is in the **unit test**.

The problem is when it throws:

`org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException`

My unit test failed with error :

`java.lang.AssertionError: Response header 'content-type' expected:<application/json;charset=UTF-8> but was:<null>`

**Controller:**

```
@PostMapping("/import")
public ResponseEntity<StatusModel> import(@Valid @RequestBody ImportModel importModel ){
    //logic
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new StatusModel("Data accepted."), HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

**Unit Test:**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MockConfiguration.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ModelControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    private ModelController controller;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void import_validRequest_imported() throws Exception {

        mockMvc
            .perform(
                post("/import")
                    .content(VALID_CONTENT).contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(header().string("content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status", equalTo("Data accepted")));
    }

    @Test
    public void import_invalidRequest_notImported() throws Exception {    
        mockMvc
            .perform(
                post("/import")
                    .content(INVALID_CONTENT).contentType("application/json"))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(header().string("content-type", "application/json"));  <----- This assertion failed
    }   
}
```

**MockHttpServletRequest log:**

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /import
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json]}

Handler:
             Type = com.test.ModelController
           Method = public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.model.StatusModel> com.ModelController.import(com.test.model.ImportModel)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 400
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Why is the content type, error message is empty?

Comment: Just curious if you've tried to add `produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"` in `@PostMapping`?

Comment: yeap tried this, but still not working

Comment: Could you show your `@RestControllerAdvice`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the rational why mock mvc doesn't support spring boot exception handlers followed by recommendation and fix.

Rational excerpt

> Spring Boot's error handling is based on Servlet container error
>   mappings that result in an ERROR dispatch to an ErrorController.
>   MockMvc however is container-less testing so with no Servlet container
>   the exception simply bubbles up with nothing to stop it.
>
> So MockMvc tests simply aren't enough to test error responses
>   generated through Spring Boot. I would argue that you shouldn't be
>   testing Spring Boot's error handling. If you're customizing it in any
>   way you can write Spring Boot integration tests (with an actual
>   container) to verify error responses. And then for MockMvc tests focus
>   on fully testing the web layer while expecting exceptions to bubble
>   up.
>
> This is a typical unit vs integration tests trade off. You do unit
>   tests even if they don't test everything because they give you more
>   control and run faster.

Recommendation excerpt

> How can we write tests for error conditions using default spring-boot
>   JSON responses, then?
>
> @xak2000 Rossen's already covered this, but I wanted to give you a
>   direct answer. If you really want to test the precise format of the
>   error response then you can use an integration test using
>   @SpringBootTest configured with a DEFINED_PORT or RANDOM_PORT web
>   environment and TestRestTemplate.

Complete details here 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7321

Fix

Here is slightly different error validation using Spring Boot test.

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@SpringBootTest(classes = DemoApplication.class,
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ModelControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    void import_invalidRequest_notImported() throws JSONException {

        String expected = "{\"status\":400,\"error\":\"Bad Request\",\"message\":\"JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'Invalid': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Invalid': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')\\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 8]\",\"path\":\"/import\"}";

        String invalidJson = "Invalid";

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(invalidJson, headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("/import", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, response.getStatusCode());
        assertEquals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, response.getHeaders().getContentType());
        JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, response.getBody(), false);

    }

}
```

Reference here 
https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-rest-integration-test-example/