# Spring Boot 404 : no handler found exception in Controller Advice isn't catched

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, controller-advice

So I am trying to send a customized answer when user is trying to call an url unknown to my application. To do that I first added to my **application.properties** (in both main and test folders)

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.web.resources.add-mappings=false
```

So that if no handler is found an exception is thrown. This exception should be of type **NoHandlerFoundException**

Then I added in my controller advice a custom exception handler
my controller advice (simplified)

```java
@EnableWebMvc // (I tried with and without it doesn't change the error)
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) // (I tried with and without it doesn't change the error)
public class ExceptionsHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    // invalid route handler
    @Override
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ResponseBody
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNoHandlerFoundException(
    NoHandlerFoundException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        String error = "No handler found for " + ex.getHttpMethod() + " " + ex.getRequestURL();

        ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), error);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError.getErrors(), new HttpHeaders(), apiError.getStatus());
    }
}
```

Using this, when calling an unknown url in my test using :

```java
this.mvc.perform(get("/ttt"))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isNotFound())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.error").value("No Handler found for GET /ttt"));
```

I get in my debug console :
`o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound : No mapping for GET /ttt`
Though, answer doesn't have my custom error message as I also get in my debug console :

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

**I then tried**

```java
    @ExceptionHandler({NoHandlerFoundException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleNoHandler(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex) {
        String error = ex.getMessage();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
```

But then a **Illegal state exception : Failed to load application context** is thrown with cause

`IllegalStateException:Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.framework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException]`

**ALso**, When I put breakpoints in my handlers and debug my test, the execution never stops at any breakpoint.

Comment: I also tried using in my application.properties
`
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern= /**
spring.web.resources.add-mappings=false
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that MockMvc has trouble with building MockHttpServletRequest when using exception handlers thus the empty content.
When I run my springboot application and try calling an unknown url in my navigator, **It works**. I have the expected `error 404; with body : No handler found` using the **override method**.

see more here, stack accepted answer with 100+ usefulness score -> [Unit test MockHttpServletRequest not returning content type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61455449/unit-test-mockhttpservletrequest-not-returning-content-type)

Comment: I stopped using MockMvc to use org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate; and it works well for me. I was able to test all my cases